# Moment-generating function of a random variable with mean 0 and variance 1

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

Consider a random variable $X$ with mean $0$ and variance $1$. Given $0 < d < 1$, do we have

### $$E(e^{d X}) \leq 1 + O(d^2)$$

(it's true when $|X| \leq 1$)

Comment: No, $\mathbb{E}(\exp(dX))$ need not exist for $d>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $X \sim N(0,1)$.

We know that $\mathbb{E}[e^{dX}]=e^{d^2/2}$, which is clearly not $O(d^2)$. So the answer is no, based on this counter-example.

Comment: It is $e^{d^2/2} \leq 1 + d^2$ when $0 < d < 1$ (I didn't ask for $E(e^{dX})$ to be $O(d^2)$ but $1+O(d^2)$).

Comment: Interesting, I wonder if the normal RV example can be used to construct a proof...